# Record is not added in to the database codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

i am a begineer of codeigniter 4.i had a problem is Record is not added in to the database. i got the url link like this http://localhost:8080/index.php/usersCreate error said Whoops!
We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later... . i don't know how to solve problem what i tried so far i attached below.

**View**
User.php

```
 <form method="post" id="add_create" name="add_create" action="<?php echo site_url('usersCreate');?>">
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                           <label>First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="empid" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="fname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                           <label>Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="lname">
                        </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-6" align="center"> 

                        <Button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 80px;">Submit</Button>
              
                        </div>
                     
                 </form>
```

**Controller
User.php**

```
    public function index()
    {
        return view('User');
    }

// insert data
public function store() {
    $userModel = new UserModel();
    $data = [
        'fname' => $this->request->getVar('fname'),
        'lname'  => $this->request->getVar('lname'),
    ];
    $userModel->insert($data);
    return $this->response->redirect(site_url('users'));
}
```

**UserModel**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models;


class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'records';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    
    protected $allowedFields = ['fname', 'lname'];
}
```

**Routes**

```
$routes->get('/', 'User::index');

$routes->post('usersCreate', 'User::store');
```

Comment: as a sidenote: php uses the name attribute not the id attribute. im assuming $this->request->getVar('fname') is empty/null, and there should be $this->request->getVar('empid'), not sure if that solves your problem

Comment: i correct it but it wont work

Comment: First thing when you start developing on CI4 is setting your environment to development so you will see actual errors instead of "Whoops looks like we hit a snag". To do so please find a file named "end", rename it to ".env" and change `CI_ENVIRONMENT = production` to `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development`. Then post your error message and it will be clearer for everyone.

Comment: Without seeing any errors it will be hard to help you out buddy.

Comment: Error displayed on console like this usersCreate:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know CodeIgniter per se, but you should figure out how to get more meaningful data. Is your environment set to development environment? Usually you will get more info than `Whoops! We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later...` and get more details on the error.

But I see you're trying to go to the page, where you add a user. There's 2 ways to methods to reach that page, `GET` (this is when you just go to the page as usual) and `POST` (this is when you submit the form).

But the request data will only be available if you submit the form. Thus you have to differentiate between the 2 methods. In your Controller you need to do something like

```
if ($this->request->getMethod() === 'post') { ... }
```

which is when you submit the form.

Check out https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html which should have more info. Snippet

```
public function create()
{
    $model = new NewsModel();

    if ($this->request->getMethod() === 'post' && $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[255]',
            'body'  => 'required'
        ]))
    {
        $model->save([
            'title' => $this->request->getPost('title'),
            'slug'  => url_title($this->request->getPost('title'), '-', TRUE),
            'body'  => $this->request->getPost('body'),
        ]);

        echo view('news/success');

    }
    else
    {
        echo view('templates/header', ['title' => 'Create a news item']);
        echo view('news/create');
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: <form method="post" id="add_create" name="add_create" action="<?php echo site_url('usersCreate');?>"> submit the form and  
$routes->post('usersCreate', 'User::store');

Comment: I would suggest getting more info from the exception first. Easiest way would be to set your environment to development, look here for more info: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html#environment-variables-and-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

I normally use a short method to get data and then submit it to the database. Here is what id do. check this. I am just updating your code

```php
// insert data
public function store() {
    $userModel = new \App\Models\UserModel();
    $data = [
        'fname' => $this->request->getPost('fname'),
        'lname'  => $this->request->getPost('lname'),
    ];
    $userModel->insert($data);
    return redirect()->to(site_url('users'));
}
```

then check you html file you are missing the firstname name
Try this one

```html
 <form method="post" id="add_create" action="<?php echo site_url('usersCreate');?>">
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                           <label>First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="fname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                           <label>Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="lname">
                        </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-6" align="center"> 

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 80px;">Submit</button>
              
                        </div>
                     
                 </form>
```

For the check your model i think is not configured well check this one

```php
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $returnType     = 'object';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = false;

    protected $allowedFields = ['fname', 'lname', 'email']; // did you add this side of the site model

    protected $useTimestamps = false;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';

    protected $validationRules    = [];
    protected $validationMessages = [];
    protected $skipValidation     = false;
}
```

Check my code if it did not help you call my attentions okay. I am still ready to help

Comment: I have updated my code please try it i think this work

Comment: can you come to team viwer

Comment: So how can you connect to me

Comment: Here is my email: dchibuezen [at] gmail [dot] com

Comment: i sent it let me know that did you get it

Comment: did u see the project sir

Comment: No, access not granted. Give me access to the google drive file in other to work on it

Comment: Yes i will send it to your mail now

Comment: sir i havn't got it till now.